# How to call Shoes methods from inside an instance method?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am trying to extend a Ruby application I've already written to use Shoes. I have a class that I've already written and I want to be able to use a GUI with that class. That is, I want my class to have something like this:

```
class MyClass
   def draw
    # draw something using Shoes
  end
end
```

Another method inside `MyClass` will call `draw()` when it wants to draw something.

I've tried doing this in several ways and none of them seem to work. I could wrap the entire class in a Shoes app. Let's say I want to draw an oval:

```
Shoes.app {
  class MyClass
    def draw
      oval :top => 100, :left => 100, :radius => 30
    end
  end
}
```

But then it says `undefined method 'oval' for MyClass`.

I also tried this:

```
class MyClass
  def draw
    Shoes.app {
      oval :top => 100, :left => 100, :radius => 30
    }
  end
end
```

This runs successfully but it opens a new window every time `test()` is called.

How can I draw things using Shoes from inside an instance method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Shoes.app { ... }` does an instance_eval of the code block. What that means is the that the body of the block gets executed as though self were an instance of `Shoes` (or whatever class it is using under the hood). What you'll want to do is something like the following:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end
  def draw
    @app.oval :top => 100, :left => 100, :radius => 30
  end
end

Shoes.app {
  myclass = MyClass.new(self) # passing in the app here
  myclass.draw
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is separate the GUI from the drawing. The reason a new windows is opened every time is that Shoes.app is called everytime the draw method is called.

Try this:

```
class MyClass
  def draw
    oval :top => 100, :left => 100, :radius => 30
  end
  def test
    draw
  end
end

Shoes.app do
  myclass = MyClass.new
  myclass.test
end
```

Comment: That code doesn't work. It says `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` although I don't see why.